# Count common words

Tags: python

I have two files .txt and I should compare them and just count common words.What I should get is just a total count of how many words in common 2 different files have. How I can do it? Can you help me? This is the code that I have try, but I need only the total count ex "I have found 125 occurrences"

Comment: have you tried something then share code

Comment: Why don't you use a simple for loop and check all values where `dct[i] > 0` ? This is the solution if you want minimal changes to your code.

Answer (score 0):

So now you have a dict with non-zero values for common words. Counting them is as simple as:

```
sum(v != 0 for v in dct.values())
```

Comment: @Connery67 how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I would create one set for each of the files with its words but I would also convert anything to lower to be sure that I ll have "proper" matches. Then I would create an intersection of those sets and just get the length.

```
file1_words = set()    
file2_words = set()

file1 = open("text1.txt")
file2 = open("verbs.txt")

for word in file1.read().strip().split():
    file1_words.add(word.lower())

for word in file2.read().strip().split():
    file2_words.add(word.lower())

print(file1_words)
print(file2_words)

common_words = file1_words.intersection(file2_words)

print(len(common_words))
```

Based on your explanation, what you want to do is to sum the values of the dictionary you have created. You can do this simply by:

`print(sum(dct.values()))`

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with numerical count

Comment: So you mean the total which each of the common words appears right? For example if hello appears 2 times and apple 3 then you should get 5 right?

Comment: Then based on bereal's answer you should be able to use the sum values approach. I edited

Answer (score 0):

This counts all the occurences of the words in common.

It uses `Counter` see https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f:
    words1 = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read().lower())
    
with open('verbs.txt', 'r') as f:
    words2 = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read().lower())
    
counter1 = Counter(words1)
counter2 = Counter(words2)

common = set(counter1.keys()).intersection(counter2.keys())

sum([counter1[e] + counter2[e] for e in common])
```